# Why my internet speed is very inconsistent/slow with switch

Tags: networking, internet, home-networking, ethernet

I recently bought a switch http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833156250

so I could get more ethernet ports in my room. All I had to do was plug in an ethernet cable from my router into the switch, and then plugged a few more devices into the switch.

They both had a good working Internet connection for a few hours, and then all the devices connected to the switch slowed down or frequently disconnected.

Using speedtest, I usually get about 35-40 mb/s when connected without the switch. Using the switch, I get anywhere from 1mb/s to 15, rarely will I get my normal speed, even when I'm only using 1 device on the switch.

Is it a bad switch, or do I need to configure something different?

Comment: its an unmanaged switch so there isn't much to configure. your lan connections should auto configure, but you may want to make sure that you have them set to 1gb/full duplex. some manufacturers auto-detection algorithms don't work well with others. if you are using linux, what does ethtool say about your link?

Comment: I've had frequent problems with unmanaged gigabit switches where "auto negotiate" causes slowing/dropping. Manually configuring helped but some users would "pry" and end up reverting my hard work. Bought a managed switch and set the user's to 100mbps works a treat.

Comment: @FrankThomas The color of the light is green on the switch which indicates it's at 1gb (if that's what you're asking). And I'm using Windows, is there an equivalent test? Thanks

Comment: Did you change any network settings in your router or PC from their defaults? In particular, did you change any of the speed or duplex settings? (Did you try to force gigabit? Or force full duplex?) Even if you don't think you did, I'd double check both ends to make sure they're all set to auto negotiate.

Comment: have you tried disabling jumbo frame on your nics? I've had trouble in past getting that to work right with cheap switches.